# Failed to create thumbnail error fills gnome-session.log.1 to 50 GB!

Tags: upstart, log, thumbnails

Yesterday I got a message that my /home partition was full so I moved a 10 gb folder to a external hdd. now I got the message again so I did the Disc Usage Analyzer, and I found a 50 GB file in `/home/.cache/upstart` named `gnome-session.log.1`.

I I could not read the file so I deleted the file now and it immediately starts filling up with this message

```
(nautilus:2930): GnomeDesktop-WARNING **: Failed to create thumbnail /home/wouter/.cache/thumbnails/large/13b82fd16426ec5a8f99f1aa286de1f1.png.92B5CX: Fatal error in PNG image file: Write Error
```

I don't really get what is going on here, the file `13b82fd16426ec5a8f99f1aa286de1f1.png` does exist, but I don't think I have used it today anywhere.

How do I prevent this log from filling up again?

Comment: Just a comment: that filename is actually the md5 hash of the original file.

Comment: I was wondering about the weird name ^^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions:

**1. CLEAR THUMBNAIL CACHE**
Run the following commands to clear your thumbnails cache.

```
rm -r ~/.thumbnails
killall nautilus
```

**2. Install Samba**
If you don't have samba installed, you can try installing it.

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

**3. Disable 'file manager' plugin in GEdit**
Open Gedit and go to "Edit >Preferences > Plugins" and turn off the File Browser pane.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2123796.html

Comment: I think the clearing the thumbnail cache did the job, I'll keep a eye on it but it appears that it stopped adding the error messages.